# "Activation of network connection failed"

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I receive an `Activation of network connection failed` error when trying to connect to my home wifi network. I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo laptop. Other devices are able to connect to my home wifi and I can connect my Ubuntu laptop to the internet with an ethernet cable at home. Also, my Ubuntu laptop can connect to other wifi networks with no issues, it is only my home wifi network where I get this error.

My wireless card is an Intel Wifi 6 AX200.

I can see the following error from `dmesg` after trying to connect:

```
deauthenticating from <MAC Address of Router> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

Any help or additional tools for diagnosing this problem would be very helpful.

Comment: Thr error message is the result of previous errors (not shown). Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager`.